# Stop element while touchmove is firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a div that I am using for touch events to expand a mobile menu I am building.  Here is my code thus far:

```
$("#" + obj.mobileButtonID).on({
    touchmove: function (e) {
        var touch = e.originalEvent.targetTouches[0],
        if (touch.pageX < 0) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        } else if (touch.pageX > 200) {
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
        $(this).css({ left: touch.pageX });
});
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is stop the `touchmove` event at certain places.  Say if the div is over a certain `pageX` coordinate or under it.  I feel like that this is close, but it's not working exactly right.  Every time a `touchmove` event fires, it completely ignores my conditional and keeps going past the coordinates I've laid out.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You stop the propagation of the event in your conditionals but the left css property is still being applied. If your desire is to prevent this, then exit your event handler by returning from the conditionals. The propagation is for propagating the event to `DOM` elements higher in the `DOM` hierarchy.

Comment: Your answer to this actually sparked the answer I was looking for.  I just put the last thing in an `else` statement and it works like a dream.  Thanks for this!  Will give you the checkmark.